# Node.js (ES6) - Promise control flow with Promise.all

Tags: node.js, request, queue, promise, es6-promise

I am attempting to create a queue that processes parallel HTTP requests.

A request object is generated for each HTTP request e.g.

```
{
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'http://posttestserver.com/post.php',
    body: {
        some: 'foo'
    },
    json: true
}
```

I pass in an array of these objects and wish to add them to the queue and then execute the actual request.

**PROBLEM**: The Promise.all statement waits for all requests to complete before returning.

**QUESTION**: I wish to add all tasks to the queue and **return after each request** has completed, not wait for them all. Can anyone advise how to separate the logic to make the request from adding the tasks to the queue?

NOTE: promise-queue and request-promise both return promises.

Here's what I have:

```
"use strict";

const Queue = require("promise-queue");
const rp = require('request-promise');

const maxConcurrent = 10;
const maxQueue = Infinity;
const queue = new Queue(maxConcurrent, maxQueue);

var options = [
    {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: 'http://posttestserver.com/post.php',
        body: {
            some: 'foo'
        },
        json: true
    },{
        method: 'POST',
        uri: 'http://posttestserver.com/post.php',
        body: {
            some: 'bar'
        },
        json: true
    }
];

Promise.all(options.map(function(task) {
        return queue.add(function() {
            return rp(task);
        })
    }))
    .then(function(response) {
        log(response);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        log(err);
    });


function log(data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 4));
}
```

Comment: Have your try to use Promise.race([p1,p2],callback) to get the result from a Promises list.

Comment: My mistake, the Promise.race only get the result from the first 'resloved' Promise

Comment: I'm struggling with " return after each request has completed".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend calling the chain of promises inside a forEach loop, like so:

```js
var queueTask = function(task) {
  // returns a promise
  return queue.add(function() { return rp(task); });
};

var logResponse = function(response) {
  console.log(response);
};

var catchErrors = function(err) {
  console.log(err);
};

options.forEach(opt => {
  queueTask()
    .then(logResponse)
    .catch(catchErrors);
})
```

**UPDATE**

In the comments it was mentioned that the above snippet doesn't give you a way to know when the last task is complete. This wasn't a requirement of the original question, but since some comments said it might be useful, here's one way you could accomplish that using promises:

```js
var runTasks = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

  var queueTask = function(task) {
    // returns a promise
    return queue.add(function() { return rp(task); });
  };

  var logResponse = function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  };

  var catchErrors = function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  };

  options.forEach((opt, i, arr) => {
    
    queueTask()
      .then(logResponse)
      .catch(catchErrors);
    
    if (i === arr.length-1) { resolve(); }
    
  });
  
});

var functionToRunWhenLastTaskCompletes = function() {
  console.log('All tasks are complete.');
};

// runTasks is a promise here, not a function
// so you don't need to call it like a function
runTasks
  .then(functionToRunWhenLastTaskCompletes)
```

Comment: Thanks @dwhieb - thats ideal, very helpful indeed!

Comment: @Ben - Note, this will not let you know when the last task is done if that's something you wanted to know.  That's what `Promise.all()` is useful for.

Comment: @jfriend00 - thats a good point. In this case that is not a requirement but thanks for the comment. Im not sure how I would approach that just yet. Will give it some further thought ;)